# Can we stop refreshing whole page when we click on delete link using javascript?

Tags: custom, object

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Campaign Member List" columns="1" id="memberList">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!memberList}" var="member">
         <apex:column >
             <apex:commandLink onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!member.id}')" status="deleteStatus" oncomplete="">Delete</apex:commandLink>
          </apex:column>

       <apex:column value="{!member.FirstName}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!member.Type}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!member.Association_Date__c}"/>

 </apex:pageblocktable>    
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Please tell me solution on this

Comment: use rerender attribute of apex:commandlink

Comment: I used but it refreshing whole page

Comment: can you please share the deleteCaseNote code and its related functions/action function code if any present ?

Comment: Please Browse on Ajax tags.And you can simply refresh based on requirements.@Nikita

Answer (score 1):

I presume that deleteCaseNote is an actionFunction, in which case, you can just abort the original click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!member.id}'); return false;">Delete</a>
```

You can specify the "status" and "reRender" attributes on your actionFunction instead.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="deleteCaseNote" reRender="memberList" action="{!deleteMember}" status="deleteStatus">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!memberId}" value="" name="memberId" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```